# sync files on TFS and Local manually without internet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

i have downloaded project in zip file and map local folder with server , but it doesnt detect that my files are latest version , how configure tfs in vs 2012 that this files are latest without checkin all solution via internet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A latest version check is performed by querying the server to see what the latest version of a file is in the central source repository (i.e. on the server).

If you've got a local workspace, then you would normally be using 'workspace version' checks, which are performed using the contents of the .tfs folder. You will need to have already performed a 'get latest' operation in order to populate that folder.

If you're using a server workspace, then all source control operations are performed against the server.

Remember that Team Foundation Version Control is a centralised source control system, so you should always get your code by connecting to the server.  I understand if your internet connection is poor that this can be a problem at times. If it is, you might want to consider using a [TFS Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee248710.aspx) to help.